# Get filename and arguments from path on Windows system (with Python)

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

Im running into a issue when Im trying to get the filename and arguments from a binary path.

For example, here is the binary path that is giving me trouble:

```
binaryPath = "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec \V"
```

Ideally, I would like the result to be:

```
filename: "msiexec.exe"
arguments: "\V"
```

Here is what I have tried (and this works for 99% of paths with arguments, just not the one above). And obviously the "//V" is messing this up and os.path is looping it in with the filepath.

```
import os

binaryPath = "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec \V"

fn_with_arguments = os.path.basename(binaryPath)
image = fn_with_arguments[0].replace("'","")
arguments = " ".join(fn_with_arguments[1:])
if image:
    print("Image: {}".format(image))

if arguments:
    print("Arguments: {}".format(arguments))

>>> Image: V
```

Any ideas? Speed is of importance here so I dont really want to split the path into pieces and then iterate to find the piece with a "dot" in it...